# List SQL Table Relationships with composite keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

What would be the SQL to list table relationships, with the composite keys/foreign fields *correctly* lined up together? Here's what I mean:

I use the SQL below to get the table relationships:

```
SELECT
    c.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    cu.TABLE_SCHEMA AS ReferencingSchema,
    cu.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencingTable,
    cu.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencingColumn,
    ku.TABLE_SCHEMA AS ReferencedSchema,
    ku.TABLE_NAME AS ReferencedTable,
    ku.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS c
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON
        cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku ON
        ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Which works great for single-column primary keys, but when composite keys are involved things fall apart. e.g. for the FK below there are 2 columns that participate in the relationship, but 4 misaligned results are returned (because of cartesian products):

```
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|CONSTRAINT_NAME          |ReferencingTable  | ReferencingColumn | ReferencedTable   | ReferencedColumn |
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | CHAINID           | CHAIN             | CHAINID          |
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | CHAINID           | CHAIN             | NTENTID          |
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | NTENTID           | CHAIN             | CHAINID          |
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | NTENTID           | CHAIN             | NTENTID          |
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I would want the result to be:

```
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|CONSTRAINT_NAME          |ReferencingTable  | ReferencingColumn | ReferencedTable   | ReferencedColumn |
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | CHAINID           | CHAIN             | CHAINID          |
|FK_ACCOUNT_CHAINID_CHAIN | ACCOUNT          | NTENTID           | CHAIN             | NTENTID          |
+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Now I could use a natural-like join on Referencing- and Referenced-columns to line up the fields - by adding `AND cu.COLUMN_NAME = ku.COLUMN_NAME` to the join, but that would only work if the names are the same and in many instances they are not (not of my doing).

---

I looked in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` and that has the `Ordinal_Position` field for ordering the primary keys, but I haven't seen a similar column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` and I'm not sure where else to look.

So if/where/how can I line up the referencing and referenced columns in a composite table relationship?

---

Applies to SQL Server 2008 R2 and above.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you want to display only distinct values. ?  In that case us Distinct in select statement

Comment: @Backtrack Not quite. The referencing and referenced columns are different so distinct won't work. In the example, I'm trying to tie `CHAINID` in `ReferencingColumn` to `CHAINID` in `ReferencedColumn` and `NTENDID` in `ReferencingColumn` to `NTENDID` in `ReferencedColumn`. But if there is any difference in the column names, they won't tie out if I rely on their name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you what you need, however I used `sys` schema views, instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
select
    quotename(fk.name) CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    quotename(s.name) + '.' + (t.name) ReferencingTable,
    quotename(c.name) ReferencingColumn,
    quotename(s2.name) + '.' + quotename(t2.name) ReferencedTable,
    quotename(c2.name) ReferencedColumn
from sys.foreign_keys fk
    join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    join sys.tables t on t.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    join sys.tables t2 on t2.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
    join sys.schemas s2 on s2.schema_id = t2.schema_id
    join sys.columns c on c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id and c.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    join sys.columns c2 on c2.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id and c2.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
order by fk.name, fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

The above will return information for all FKs.

You can filter composite by adding where clause:

```
select ...
from ...
where
    (select count(1) from sys.foreign_key_columns where constraint_object_id = fk.object_id) > 1
order by fk.name, fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. I don't think I would have gotten to this point using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`